# Fatal error 'Invalid data received"

Tags: php, curl

I'm fiddling with a free API and all is well but occasionally I get the error below.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid data received, please make sure connection is working and requested API exists' in /MY SERVER PATH/functions.php:39 Stack trace: #0 /MY SERVER PATH/index.php(5): myFunc('getInfo') #1 {main} thrown in /MY SERVER PATH/functions.php on line 39
```

Im just curious as to why this is happening?

Below are relevant codes for reference.

thanks all for the extra help.

---

SNIPPET FROM FUNCTIONS.PHP

```
function myFunc($method, array $req = array()) {
    // API settings
    $key = 'MY API KEY'; // your API-key
    $secret = 'MY SECRET'; // your Secret-key

    $req['method'] = $method;
    $mt = explode(' ', microtime());
    $req['nonce'] = $mt[1];

    // generate the POST data string
    $post_data = http_build_query($req, '', '&');

    $sign = hash_hmac("sha512", $post_data, $secret);

    // generate the extra headers
    $headers = array(
            'Sign: '.$sign,
            'Key: '.$key,
    );

    // our curl handle (initialize if required)
    static $ch = null;
    if (is_null($ch)) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; PHP client; '.php_uname('s').'; PHP/'.phpversion().')');
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'URL TO THE API');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    // run the query
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($res === false) throw new Exception('Could not get reply: '.curl_error($ch));
    $dec = json_decode($res, true);
    if (!$dec) throw new Exception('Invalid data received, please make sure connection is working and requested API exists');
    if (!$dec){
        echo '';
    }else{
    return $dec;
    }
```

}

SNIPPET FROM INDEX.PHP

```
$result = myFunc("getInfo");
```

Comment: include the json in $res in the exception message, so we/you can see what the problem is.

Comment: It says so right at the bottom, doesn't it? It's throwing an exception because `curl_exec` returned `false`. Why did it return false? The server at the other end had trouble with the request. If it happens intermittently, it might be server load or a flaky connection. If it's reproducible, something is wrong with the request.

Comment: @alexis I believe you are right about server load or flaky connection because its working fine again now. btw, is there a way we can probe if its really the cause of error?

Comment: You can examine the exception message, as @mrhobo suggests. But Scallio's answer has it right: the error is actually thrown on the next line, after the json call.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
$dec = json_decode($res, true);
if (!$dec) throw new Exception('Invalid data received, please make sure connection is working and requested API exists');
```

The `!$dec` is not right here, because the server can respond with `false`, `null`, `0`, etc which can well be valid responses, but your code will take those to be an error with json_decoding. 
To check for errors with json_decode, use json_last_error instead.

```
$dec = json_decode($res, true);
$err = json_last_error();
if ($err !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) throw new Exception('Invalid data received, please make sure connection is working and requested API exists');
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the problem. btw, will that solve the issue for good? (sorry for the noob question) because right now, the code is working fine. I just don't know when the fatal error occurs again. its just erratic.

Comment: oops `Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_last_error()` how come?

Comment: json_last_error is PHP >= 5.3.x so you're probably working with an older version. Forget the above and in your original code use `$dec !== null` instead of `!$dec` as a workaround until you upgrade to 5.3. I don't know if this solves all the problems you were having as some exceptions might have been genuine problems with json_decoding, I can't tell.